# Find all the integer numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $k$ to this equation have three integer different solutions?

Tags: equation-solving

How to find all integer numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $k$ that belong to interval $[-10,10]$, so that the equation $$\sqrt[3]{a x + b} +\sqrt[3]{c x + d} + \sqrt[3]{e x + f} =k$$ has three different integer solutions? I tried

```
Reduce[{Root[#^3 - (a x + b) &, 1] + Root[#^3 - (c x + d) &, 1] + 
    Root[#^3 - (e x + f) &, 1] == k, -10 <= a <= 10, -10 <= b <= 
   10, -10 <= c <= 10, -10 <= d <= 10, -10 <= e <= 10, -10 <= f <= 
   10, -10 <= k <= 10}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, k, x}, Integers]
```

**Update**

With $k=0$, we can transform the given equation of the form
$$(a+c+e)x + b + d + f = 3\sqrt[3]{(ax + b)(cx+d)(ex+f)}$$
Cubing both sides of the equation:

```
ClearAll;
f[x_] := (a + c + e) x + b + d + f;
g[x_] := 3 ((a x + b) (c x + d) (e x + f))^(1/3);
Collect[f[x]^3 - g[x]^3, x];
Discriminant[%, x]
```

Next, we solve for `Discriminant > 0` 
But I can not get the answer.

This is some equations

- $\sqrt[3]{-2 x + 8}+ \sqrt[3]{x + 2} + \sqrt[3]{x - 10}=0$.
- $\sqrt[3]{-2 x + 4}+ \sqrt[3]{x + 6} + \sqrt[3]{x - 10}=0$.
- $\sqrt[3]{-3 x + 9}+ \sqrt[3]{x + 1} + \sqrt[3]{2x - 10}=0$.
- $\sqrt[3]{-6 x + 6}+ \sqrt[3]{4 x + 4} + \sqrt[3]{2x - 10}=0$.

Comment: Have you tried `FindInstance`? If so, please place the code so we can see.

Comment: Here's an answer: a=b=c=d=e=f=g=0.

Comment: You need to simplify this problem. Think that you have 7 variables, each of which can take 41 different values. This means that if you go the brute force way you will have $41^7 \sim 2 \times 10^11$ different combinations to examine. And you want to find _all_ integers that satisfy this equation. Also, note that in your code you seem to be happy with the values of variables being in the interval $[-10,10]$.

Comment: I think one has to look at a small number of combinations. If `r1=a x + b` and similar, then this gives the list of `{r1, r2, r2}` satisfying the equation : `rlist = {Reduce[{r1^(1/3) + r2^(1/3) + r3^(1/3) == #, 0 <= r1 <= 10, 
       0 <= r2 <= 10, 0 <= r3 <= 10}, {r1, r2, r3}, 
      Integers] /. {r_ == rsol_ -> rsol, And -> List, 
      Or -> List}, #} & /@ Range[0, 20]`. The last step is to resolve each of `{r1, r2, r3}` into triplets of integers with `Reduce` once more.

Comment: There are some ambiguities in your question. 1. $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ belong to $[−20,20]$ or to $[−10,10]$ ? 2. What about $k$ and $x$ ?

Comment: My code is $[-10,10]$, and ofcourse, it can $[-10,10]$; $k$ is parameter and $x$ is a unknown.

Comment: @minthao_2011 So why is there still in your question: "$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $k$ belongs to interval $[-20,20]$ " ? Is $x$ restricted to $[-10,10]$ either? Do you want only integer solutions ?

Comment: I have just edited $[-10,10]$. I want only integer solutionS. I think, $x$ depend on parameters.

Comment: The question, which evidently is missing several words, now reads as if you are asking for all integral values of $a,\ldots,k$ in the interval $[-10,10]$ for which your equation has three distinct integral solutions. Is this a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 4):

I presume what you have written, is an algebraic identity. Otherwise it just doesn't make sense to me.
That being the case, I can show that either k or {a,c,e} must be 0.

Since $$\sqrt[3]{a x + b} + \sqrt[3]{c x + d} + \sqrt[3]{e x + f} = k$$ is an identity, it should be valid for all values of x, including $$ x = 0 $$ which will give: $$ \sqrt[3]{b} + \sqrt[3]{d} + \sqrt[3]{f} = k $$

On the other hand we can take derivatives from both sides of an algebraic identity with respect to its variables, which happens to be x in this case. Taking the derivative:
$$\text{Simplify}\left[\frac{\partial \left(\sqrt[3]{a x+b}+\sqrt[3]{c x+d}+\sqrt[3]{e x+f}\right)}{\partial x}\right] = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{a}{(a x+b)^{2/3}}+\frac{c}{(c x+d)^{2/3}}+\frac{e}{(e x+f)^{2/3}}\right) = 0$$

It can be verified that this will happen when $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{f}=1 \And \sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{c}+\sqrt[3]{e}=0 \Rightarrow k=0  $$
OR $$ a = c = d =0.$$
You can verify this by using Mathematica:

```
Simplify[Factor[ (a/(b + a x)^(2/3) + c/(d + c x)^(2/3) + e/(f + e x)^(2/3))], Assumptions -> b^(1/3) + d^(1/3) + f^(1/3) == 0 && a == b && c == d && e == f] // Factor
```

I noticed this myself by expanding the function around x=0:

```
Series[1/3 (a/(b + a x)^(2/3) + c/(d + c x)^(2/3) + e/(f + e x)^(2/3)), {x, 0, 10}] // Simplify
```

Anyway, knowing that either $$ a=c=e=0$$ or $$a=b,c=d,e=f$$, it's pretty simple and straightforward to find all the integer solutions of a,b,c,d,e,f,k.

Comment: Your argument doesn't show $a=c=e=0$ and $a=b,c=d,e=f$ are the only solutions for the equation to be an identity. For example, I could have satisfied your derivative equation with $a=n*b, c=n*d, e=n*f$ for any integer $n$ and $\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{d}+\sqrt[3]{f} = 0$. In reality, $a=c=e=0$ is the only solution, as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a final solution, but I hope it is an useful approach:
First, define a function which depends on your variable x (for me x is a real number) and your parameters a,b,c,d,e,f (integers between -10 and 10):

```
k[x_,a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_]:=(a*x+b)^(1/3)+(c*x+d)^(1/3)+(e*x+f)^(1/3)
```

You could use a graphical solution. E.g. use

```
Manipulate[Plot[k[x,a,b,c,d,e,f],{x,-10,10},PlotRange -> {All,All}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "k"}],{a,-10,10,1},{b,-10,10,1},{c,-10,10,1},{d,-10,10,1},
{e,-10,10,1},{f,-10,10,1}]
```

[image: Plot]

As you can see, depending on x there are several integer values for k.

If you want to find for which value of x k is an integer, you can try the following (for simplicity I fix here arbitrarily c, d, e, f to 10 and k to 8):

```
bigMatrix=Quiet[Table[{a,b,If[#∈Reals,#,no]&[FindRoot[k[x,a,b,10,10,10,10]==8
(*adapt it to integers between-10 and 10*),{x,1}][[1,2]]]},
{a,-10,10,1},{b,-10,10,1}]];
```

With `Quiet` I suppress some warnings (be careful, due to the suppression there are some wrong solutions produced).

With

```
solutions = Flatten[Delete[bigMatrix, Position[bigMatrix, no][[All, {1, 2}]]], 1];
```

I delete all solutions where x is not a real number ("no").

And with

```
output = Table[k[solutions[[i, 3]], solutions[[i, 1]], solutions[[i, 2]], 10, 10, 
10, 10], {i, 1, Length[solutions]}];
solutions2 = Delete[solutions, Position[output, val_ /; val != 8]];
```

I delete all wrong solutions.

Let us take a look at one of the solutions, e.g. `solutions2[[158]]` ({10, -7, 1.59669}).

If you set in this solution in your function with `k[solutions2[[158,3]],solutions2[[158,1]],solutions2[[158,2]],10,10,10,10]`, you can see that the output is indeed 8 again.

You can find a lot of solution by changing the 8 in the `FindRoot` by some of the other integers. And you can find even more solutions if you do not fix as many parameters as I do – but then calculation times increases much (which can perhaps be improved by some better code).

**Appendix 1:**

If you are interested in a solution for fixed values of x (x ≠0), you could do the following:

Calculate all values of the function of `k` for a fixed x (e.g. x=1)

```
start=-4;
stop=4;
bigMatrixB=ParallelTable[{a,b,c,d,e,f,k[1,a,b,c,d,e,f]},{a,start,stop,1},
{b,start,stop,1},{c,start,stop,1},{d,start,stop,1},{e,start,stop,1},{f,start,stop,1}];
```

As start and stop value I have chosen -4 and 4 to avoid long calculation times.

Then filter for integer solutions with:

```
solutionsB=Flatten[bigMatrixB,5];
solutionsB2=Delete[solutionsB,Partition[Union[Position[solutionsB[[All,7]],
val_/;val∉Integers][[All,1]]],1]];
```

In this special case (a,b,c,d,e and f are going from -4 to 4 and x = 1) you can find 5832 solutions!
Among them are solutions such as 
a=-2, b=3, c=4,  d=-3, e=-3, f=4, k=3 (output of `solutionsB2[[1587]]`)
which shows you that Alis answer is not really correct (neither a=c=e=0 or a=b, c=d, e=f  is here fulfilled).

**Appendix 2:**

For the special case that x=0 your equation simplifies and also the function `k`.
In this case we have the more simple function `k2` given by:

```
k2[b_, d_, f_] := b^(1/3) + d^(1/3) + f^(1/3);
```

It does not cost much calculation time to calculate all possible values of `k2` with

```
start=-10;
stop=10;
bigMatrixC=ParallelTable[{b,d,f,k2[b,d,f]},{b,start,stop,1},{d,start,stop,1},
{f,start,stop,1}];
```

Filter again for all integer solution with:

```
solutionsC=Flatten[bigMatrixC,2];
solutionsC2=Delete[solutionsC,Partition[Union[Position[solutionsC[[All,4]],
val_/;val∉Integers][[All,1]]],1]];
```

And you will find 27 solutions for b,d,f and k which are:

`{{0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1},{0,0,8,2},{0,1,0,1},{0,1,1,2},{0,1,8,3},{0,8,0,2},{0,8,1,3},{0,8,8,4},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,2},{1,0,8,3},{1,1,0,2},{1,1,1,3},{1,1,8,4},{1,8,0,3},{1,8,1,4},{1,8,8,5},{8,0,0,2},{8,0,1,3},{8,0,8,4},{8,1,0,3},{8,1,1,4},{8,1,8,5},{8,8,0,4},{8,8,1,5},{8,8,8,6}}`

So, both appendices give you in total 5859 integer solutions to your problem. Tell us, if you need more ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are no solutions. Rewrite your equation as

```
y[i_] = a[i] x + b[i];
k = Inactive[Sum][y[i]^(1/3), {i, 1, 3}];
```

For real $k$, $y(i)$ cannot be negative, because $\sqrt[3]{y(i)} = \sqrt[3]{-1}\sqrt[3]{-y(i)}$, which, for negative $y(i)$, is a constant complex number multiplied by a positive function increasing monotonically as $y(i)$ decreases, so no cancellation of imaginary terms in $k$ is possible. Positive $y(i)$ requires

```
Reduce[{y[i] >= 0, a[i]==0},x,Reals]||
Reduce[{y[i] >= 0, a[i]<0},x,Reals]||
Reduce[{y[i] >= 0, a[i]>0},x,Reals]
```

> $$ (b(i)\geq 0\land a(i)=0)\lor \left(a(i)<0\land x\leq -\frac{b(i)}{a(i)}\right)\lor \left(a(i)>0\land x\geq -\frac{b(i)}{a(i)}\right) $$

Therefore,

$$ \max \left(\left\{\left.-\frac{b(i)}{a(i)}\right|a(i)>0\right\}\right)\leq x\leq \min \left(\left\{\left.-\frac{b(i)}{a(i)}\right|a(i)<0\right\}\right) $$

In this domain, continuity of $\sqrt[3]{y(i)}$ implies continuity of $k$.  Also, $\sqrt[3]{y(i)}$ is positive and monotonically increasing with $y(i)$.

If all $a(i)=0$, any $x$ gives the same $k$, which thus has infinitely many $x$ solutions.

Otherwise, if all $a(i)$ have the same sign, $k$ is monotonic in $x$, so each $k$ has no more than 1 $x$ solution.

Otherwise, for some $k$ to have 3 $x$ solutions, continuity requires

```
D[k, x] /. y[i] -> Defer[y[i]]
```

> $$ \underset{i=1}{\overset{3}{\sum }}\frac{a(i)}{3 y(i)^{2/3}} $$

to change signs twice. Since $\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}$ is continuous for $y(i)\geq0$, changing signs twice requires $\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}=0$ twice. However, $\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}$ can be decomposed into the sum of 2 positive functions, 1 with positive $a(i)$ increasing monotonically with $x$, and the other with negative $a(i)$ decreasing monotonically with $x$. These functions can have no more than 1 intersection, so $\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}=0$ at most once. Hence, $k$ can have no more than 2 $x$ solutions.

### Further Comments

1. Since $k$ has no more than 2 $x$ solutions unless all $a(i)=0$, the equation can only be an algebraic identity if all $a(i)=0$.
2. There are integer $k, a(i), b(i)$ with 2 $x$ solutions, e.g.

   `Solve[1 == x^(1/3) + (1 - x)^(1/3), x]`

   > $$ \{\{x\to 0\},\{x\to 1\}\} $$

One question might be to find what $k, a(i), b(i)$ have 1 or 2 $x$ solutions, but I won't work on this question unless it's of interest to anyone.